# Sendgrid System.ArgumentException: Unknown element: html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I've just update the following packages to their latest version:

a) SendGrid.SmtpApi updated to 1.3.1

b) SendGrid update to 6.0

and suddenly the WebTransport.Deliver method is not there anymore - no problem, I've switched to DeliverAsync method but now I get a very strange error, that it's supposed to be fixed since 2 years ago:

> System.ArgumentException: Unknown element: html

This is part of the stack trace that can be of interest:

> System.ArgumentException: Unknown element: html
>
> at SendGrid.ErrorChecker.CheckForErrors(HttpResponseMessage response,
>   Stream stream)
>
> at SendGrid.ErrorChecker.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at SendGrid.Web.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)

And also this is how my email sending code looks like:

```
SendGridMessage emailMessage = new SendGridMessage();
emailMessage.AddTo(user.CompleteRegistrationModel.UserEmailAddress);
emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationHelper.EmailSenderAddress, ConfigurationHelper.EmailSenderName);
emailMessage.EnableTemplateEngine(ConfigurationHelper.ConfirmationEmailTemplateId);
emailMessage.AddSubstitution("-urlaplicatie-",
                new List<string>()
                {
                    String.Format("{2}{0}{1}", user.CompleteRegistrationModel.CompanyUrlPrefix,
                        ConfigurationHelper.DomainSuffix, ConfigurationHelper.ApplicationAccessProtocol)
                });
            emailMessage.AddSubstitution("-username-",
                new List<string>() {user.CompleteRegistrationModel.UserEmailAddress});
            emailMessage.AddSubstitution("-confirmationurl-",
                new List<string>() {user.CompleteRegistrationModel.UserEmailAddressConfirmationCompleteUrl});

            emailMessage.Subject = String.Format("{0}{1}", user.CompleteRegistrationModel.CompanyUrlPrefix,
                ConfigurationHelper.DomainSuffix);
            emailMessage.Text = " ";
            emailMessage.Html = " ";

            Web webTransport =
                new Web(new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationHelper.SendgridUsername,
                    ConfigurationHelper.SendgridPassword));

            try
            {
                await webTransport.DeliverAsync(emailMessage);
            }
            catch (InvalidApiRequestException exception)
            {
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(exception);
            }
```

Can, please, someone tell me what is happening?

Thank you,
Evdin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update to 6.0.1, there was a bug in 6.0.0 and it was unlisted. Thanks.

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Thanks!!!! It's working now :-) Just a personal question - I've added this issue also on the sendgrid forum and nobody answered and here the answer came in no-time.... Which is the best place to ask sendgrid related questions, here or there? THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: I'm glad it's working. For open source related questions, the best place to ask is the github repo for the library you're using. Our support team monitors the other forum, but on stackoverflow our community team and a few other engineers also contribute.

Comment: I've been getting this a lot (though not always) lately, using 6.1.0.0. Any ideas? (was working well for months up to that point)