# Not receiving email using SendGrid

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid

I am attempting to send an email using the SendGrid library: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

More specifically I am doing this...

```
// Create the email object first, then add the properties.
SendGridMessage myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
myMessage.AddTo("anna@example.com");
myMessage.From = new MailAddress("john@example.com", "John Smith");
myMessage.Subject = "Testing the SendGrid Library";
myMessage.Text = "Hello World!";

// Create credentials, specifying your user name and password.
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

// Create an Web transport for sending email.
var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

// Send the email.
transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
```

The code runs fine however I never receive an email!! How do I diagnose this problem?

Note the email doesn't appear in the Bounces/Blocks/Spam Reports or Invalid Email lists.

Comment: There was a bug in the version I was using

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876448/sendgrid-system-argumentexception-unknown-element-html

Comment: Shouldn't it be `await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);`

Comment: Do you see a Processed event in your Email Activity report?

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is an old post, but here's my answer:

SendGrid is not used for receiving emails to your email address, only to send them in mass.  If you want to use I suggest using SmtpClient from MailKit.  Be sure to use the proper hostname, like smtp.gmail.com, a port number, like 465 for SSL, and the proper credentials (Username and password of any email address).

One thing to note, if you use your own credentials for your own email address and you want to send it to that same email address, like if you want to send an email to JoeBlank@email with it's own credentials, you will only send to yourself.  If you want to reply back to a different email address, fill in the ReplyTo field.  The idea is to let the email of the authorized email address send you the message.  Here's the code:

```
using MimeKit;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage();
        message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender Name", "sender@example.com"));
        message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Receiver Name", "receiver@example.com"));
        message.ReplyTo.Add(new MailboxAddress("ReplyTo Name", "replyto@example.com"));
        message.Subject = "Subject";
        message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = plainTextContent
        };

        using (SmtpClient smClient = new SmtpClient())
        {
            smClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
            smClient.Authenticate("user", "pass");

            await smClient.SendAsync(message);
            smClient.Disconnect(true);
        }
```